# XPath not finding nodes

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some XML that is stored in the database and passed in as a string to my method.

```
<settings>
  <ReportOptions>
    <ReportWidget>
      <widget Name="Report Exclusions">
        <Visibility>
          <VisibilitySetting Name="ClosedLocations" Value="true"/>
        </Visibility>
      </widget>
      <widget Name="Report Period">
        <Visibility>
          <VisibilitySetting Name="Day" Value="true"/>
          <VisibilitySetting Name="Month" Value="true"/>
        </Visibility>
      </widget>
      <widget Name="Output Method">
        <Properties>
          <Visibility>
            <VisibilitySetting Name="Report Viewer" Value="true"/>
            <VisibilitySetting Name="Pdf" Value="true"/>
          </Visibility>
        </Properties>
      </widget>
    </ReportWidget>
  </ReportOptions>
</settings>
```

I run the following expression in an online XPath tester:

```
/settings/ReportOptions/ReportWidget/widget[@Name='Output Method']/Properties/Visibility/VisibilitySetting[@Name]
```

and I get the following results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
<VisibilitySetting Name="Report Viewer" Value="true"/>

<VisibilitySetting Name="Pdf" Value="true"/>

</result>
```

But when I run the following code:

```
var customizationApplied = false;
var firstProperty = Items[0];
var settings = firstProperty.Widget.Report.Settings;
var widgetName = firstProperty.Widget.Name;

// Select the node and place the results in an iterator
var strExpression =     settings.Compile("/settings/ReportOptions/ReportWidget/widget[@Name='Output Method']/Properties/Visibility/VisibilitySetting[@Name]");


var nodeIterator = settings.Select(strExpression);

// iterate through the results
while (nodeIterator.MoveNext())
{
    var xmlPropertyName = nodeIterator.Current.GetAttribute("Name", string.Empty);

    var propertyToCustomize = (from prop in Items
                               where string.Equals(prop.Name, xmlPropertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                               select prop).FirstOrDefault();

    if (propertyToCustomize != null)
    {
        var xmlPropertyValue = nodeIterator.Current.GetAttribute("Value", string.Empty);
        propertyToCustomize.IsEnabled = StringToObjectHelper.GetValue(xmlPropertyValue, false);

        customizationApplied = true;
    } 
}
```

I get no results. The nodeIterator always shows this on the mouseover:

```
Position=0, Current={Root}
```

and when I execute the nodeIterator.MoveNext() method, it returns false.

Can anyone please shed some light on what the problem could be? It all worked before and nothing has been changed.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Please add tags of the technologies you are using here. You are not using only XPath. JavaScript? What else? People who can answer your question won't find it if you don't tag it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using standard .NET's LINQ-to-XML :

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = @"<settings>
  <ReportOptions>
    <ReportWidget>
      <widget Name=""Report Exclusions"">
        <Visibility>
          <VisibilitySetting Name=""ClosedLocations"" Value=""true""/>
        </Visibility>
      </widget>
      <widget Name=""Report Period"">
        <Visibility>
          <VisibilitySetting Name=""Day"" Value=""true""/>
          <VisibilitySetting Name=""Month"" Value=""true""/>
        </Visibility>
      </widget>
      <widget Name=""Output Method"">
        <Properties>
          <Visibility>
            <VisibilitySetting Name=""Report Viewer"" Value=""true""/>
            <VisibilitySetting Name=""Pdf"" Value=""true""/>
          </Visibility>
        </Properties>
      </widget>
    </ReportWidget>
  </ReportOptions>
</settings>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes =
    doc.XPathSelectElements(
        "/settings/ReportOptions/ReportWidget/widget[@Name='Output Method']/Properties/Visibility/VisibilitySetting[@Name]");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
}
```

The output is exactly the same as you got from online XPath tester :

```
<VisibilitySetting Name="Report Viewer" Value="true"/>
<VisibilitySetting Name="Pdf" Value="true"/>
```